# Python/Selenium javascript error: argument is not defined

Tags: python, selenium, тестирование, test-automation, pytest

У меня есть метод при использовании которого я получаю ошибку:

> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: argument is not defined

вот собственно сам метод(если коротко, то его суть скролл до элемента)

```py
    def scroll_to_element(self, locator):
        return self.driver.execute_script("argument[0].scrollInToView();", locator)
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моем случае проблема была с синтаксисом я использовал argument[0], а нужно arguments[0], то есть верный код будет выглядеть вот так:

```py
    def scroll_to_element(self, locator):
        return self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollInToView();", locator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит о том, что метод scrollIntoView не является функцией у объекта, который вы пытаетесь использовать. Возможно, вы пытаетесь использовать метод на неправильном объекте или элемент не поддерживает этот метод. Проверьте, что элемент, к которому вы пытаетесь проскроллиться, является элементом DOM и поддерживает метод scrollIntoView.

```
def scroll_to_element(self, locator):
    return self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", locator)
```